# Include a layout and a custom title in a activity

Tags: android

I am including a layout inside main layout, and if I use custom title in the activity which loads the main layout I am getting the following error.

> Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine
>   custom titles with other title features

I have checked the styles and manifest.

If I remove custom title or included layout it is working, but I need to use the both.

Answer (score 0):

use `<include>` tag to include your layout.

`<include layout="@layout/YourLayoutName" />`

use below code to set title

`if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("YourTitle");`